# Why Am I in 6th in my clan? how do I get higher?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have So many more things than another player called Sam L-H in clash of clans, but in war he is in 5 Place and I am in 6. My question is how are we placed in clash of clans wars, Why am I in 6 And Sam is in 5.

Comment: Trophies dont determine your placement in war. Its a combination of your town hall level, defense strength, and troop strength

Answer (score 1):

Official answer from Supercell:

> `Once a match is found, players are sorted on the map from strongest to weakest, in terms of defence power of their base, i.e., defense levels, hero levels, traps, etc.`

Source: http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/237478-Clan-Wars-FEEDBACK-here